# How to multiply a set number and a user input number in Java?

Tags: java, input

I want to make a calculator that greets the user by name then multiplies one number that the user enters and one number that I set. For instance, if the user enters the number 10, I want my code to take the 10 and multiply it by 6.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {

    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        Scanner userInputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println ("Hello, my name is Bob. What is your name?");

        String userName = userInputScanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println ("Hello" + userName +  "how many steps do you take in a ten second interval?");
    }
}
```

This part is working, but I can't figure out what to do next.

Comment: Next: ask the user for the first number (using `Scanner` : `userInputScanner.nextInt()`)
Then: ask the user for the second number  (using `Scanner` : `userInputScanner.nextInt()`)
Then multiply the numbers and show the user the response (using `System.out.println`)

Answer (score 0):

Use `nextInt()` (or `nextDouble()` or ...) method to read the number the user will input.

```
int userNumber = (userInputScanner.hasNext()) ? userInputScanner.nextInt() : 0;
System.out.println("6 * " + userNumber + " = " + (6 * userNumber));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the [Javadoc for Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), there is a `nextInt()` method, which will do the same thing as `nextLine()` but return an integer. You can set that to an integer variable.

To multiply two variables, it's as simple as

```
int z = x * y;
```

Then print out the result, or to simplify it, you could just print out the calculation without setting it equal to a variable

```
System.out.println("The awnser is: " + (scanner.nextInt() * 6));
```

Keep in mind, this are integers, you could also use doubles or floats, or even longs. See the scanner documentation for all the methods you can use to get input.